# How to create image like this?

Tags: tools, image-editing, highlights

So, I have an image like this: 
[image]

in which I want to highlight the "Advanced" section on the left side of the image like the image below:
[image]

How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: What software do you have access to? What have you tried? What has failed? Please [edit your question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/posts/122166/edit) and add the missing information. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In many programs you have layers. For example I work a lot with paint.net but this might work with other programs too:

1. try to add a gray or black colored layer above the image you have.
2. set the layer opacity to a value for which you want the darker part to look like.
3. delete the area from the layer you want to highlight.

Hope this works for you!